# Volume comparison for scalar curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

I'm reading Gromov's article "*Four lectures on scalar curvature*". On the page 7, he states a volume comparison theorem for small balls without proof. I want to know **how** to prove it or **where** I can find its proof.

The article can be found on arXiv:1908.10612v6.

I would like to restate this theorem here:

If the scalar curvature of $n$-dimensional manifolds $X$ and $X'$ at some points $x\in X$ and $x'\in X'$ are related by the strict inequality $$Sc(X)(x)<Sc(X')(x')$$ then the Riemannian volumes of the $\varepsilon$-balls around these points satisfy $$vol(B_x(X,\varepsilon))>vol(B_{x'}(X',\varepsilon))$$for all sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0.$

Comment: The scalar curvature $S$ will appear in the asymptotic expansion of the volume of geodesic balls, precisely,
$$vol(B_r(x))=\omega_nr^n\left(1−\frac{Sr^2}{6(n+2)}+O(r^4)\right) \quad \text{as}~r→0+,$$
where $\omega_n$ denotes the volume of the Euclidean unit $n$-ball.

Comment: These lectures are also available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxNELCR-TMk) I think.

Comment: @user88544 I think your comment deserves to be posted as an answer

Comment: @user88544 In Gromov's article, the scalar curvature $Sc$ is regarded as a continuous function on $X$. In the asymptotic expansion, is it right for $S=Sc(X)(x)$?